# Automatic copying of unique column values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

At Column B at sheet 1, I have the following information:

[image: https://ibb.co/LvqvkSy]

I have 1-11-2019 multiple times and the next will be 2-11-2019.

I want in column A at sheet 2, 1-11-2019 one time and below that without a blank 2-11-2019.

Example:

```
Currently:
1-11-2019
1-11-2019
1-11-2019
1-11-2019
1-11-2019
2-11-2019

And it needs to be:
1-11-2019
2-11-2019 
(In other sheet without blanks)
```

Comment: You can copy your data to the new sheet, then click on your "Data" tab in the ribbon, and click "Remove Duplicates" when having the first column selected.

Comment: So you want to remove duplicates? Can you include the code you have tried and let us know where you get stuck

Comment: Thank for the help so far guys. I have no code so far, i have used the data and remove duplicated but that doesn't give me the oppurtinity to do it automaticly. If possible i want indeed to remove the duplicates and get them in an other sheet without blanks between them

Answer (score 0):

More roads to Rome on this one, but you could try:

```
Sub RemDups()

Dim lr As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheet's codename
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("B1:B" & lr)
End With

With Sheet2 'Change according to your sheet's codename
    .Range("A1:A" & lr).Value = arr
    .Range("A1:A" & lr).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlGuess
    .Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it "automatic", you can use a formula.
Ensure the range references in the formula are somewhat larger than the size of your dates table, and change the sheet reference to suit

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Sheet9!$A2:$A100<>Sheet9!$A3:$A101)*Sheet9!$A2:$A100,ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

Ensuring that the ranges are the same size, and that the Dates are sorted, we return a `DIV/0` error unless the date being tested is not equal to the date on the next row.  If that is the case, we return the date, using the `AGGREGATE` function to ignore the errors.

[image]

[image]